# Asterisk Installation On Server (Boot issue,boot: command shown instead of root user login)

Tags: installation, boot

Good day guys.I need fast help please i am going mad already.I am installing asterisk with freepbx on my server.All goes good,installation is done,but instead of going to CMD and asking me to login as root user,asterisk gone myself to again same installation screen.I am using tutorial on official docs from here

[Asterisk installation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Installing+AsteriskNOW)

Anyway if i press esc on my server,it goes to CMD but with BOOT: as command and i have no clue how to ssh to my server with this.
From link above the 12th part do not happen to me...What i should do?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry im slow.....I had to remove the attached ISO on the server side ....What a lack of logic....